# What would be the right way to present business objects in the front end?

Tags: angular, typescript, architecture, rxjs, angular6

There is a backend that returns list of persons.
It gets automatically mapped into collection of TypeScript busness object class (Person) objects using Angular/rxjs.

```
export class Person {
   Id: string;
   Name: string;
   Age: number;
}
```

There is a need to display these entities in a list with an additional column, stating whether records are selected or not - required for further processing.

The question is - what would be the right way to do this?

Should I create a `PersonModel` class that inherits from `Person` and add additional field in there?

```
export class PersonModel extends Person {
   Selected: boolean;
}
```

Or, should I ignore the fact that back-end has nothing to do with the `Selected` property and simply add the property to the `Person` class?

```
export class Person {
   Id: string;
   Name: string;
   Age: number;
   Selected: boolean;
}
```

Are there other, more proper ways of dealing with such situation?

Comment: Composition, perhaps, an object like `{ person: Person, selected: boolean }`.

Comment: Create a PersonRow class/interface with a field person of type Person and a field selected of type boolean?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Class, You can create an interface which extends another interface.

```
export interface Person {
   Id: string;
   Name: string;
   Age: number;
}

export interface PersonAttrib extends Person {
   Selected: boolean;
}
```